# Use same app on multiple domains

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a Social Media management webapp. This webapp will be used by our customers on there own sites (read, own domains). The webapp connects to a facebook app that we own, to allow them to manage there pages.

I'm using the "Website" platform for the app. During development I've had the "Site URL" set to my localhost url, and the "App Domains" set to localhost. This has worked fine.

However I now realise that this app will not always be run from localhost. It will be run from many differnt domains. I've read many posts about how its not possible to do this anymore, or at least the max is 5 domains by adding multiple platforms.

So how am I supposed to do this? Will I need to create an app on my profile for each customer/site? Will I have to create an app on each customers facebook account and link its app ID to our webapp?

Comment: Could I just create a new app for every site? How would the facebook app review process react to identical apps asking for identical permissions? Would they allow it through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was not so bad.

Since AccessTokens are portable, so you can generate them on a single domain, and then use them to access the API from any page.

To do this, I have setup a single page on my own server (not customers server), whos domain is in my Apps Domains property. This page just has the facebook JS SDK, and some code to handle whether or not to show a login or a logout button. I embed this as an iFrame inside my webapp (that can run from any URL). I use

`FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange' function {});`

to look for status changes, then use the the JS [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) method to send the result of this to the parent of the iFrame, who then sends it to the server. This AccessToken can then be used anywhere.